# knockout options binding controls for more than one model

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, api, knockout.js

I work in this tutorial 
http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/creating-web-apis/using-web-api-with-entity-framework/part-9

I want to generate edit form where the author is drop down list and the current author is selected I use a form similar to this

```
function getAllbooks() {
          ajaxHelper(baseUri, 'GET').done(function (data) {
              self.books(data);
          });
 <ul id="update-book" data-bind="foreach: books">
    <li>
        <div>
            <div class="item">Book ID</div> <span data-bind="text: $data.ID"></span>

        </div>
 <div class="form-group">
    <label for="inputAuthor" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Author</label>
    <div class="col-sm-10">
      <select data-bind="options:authors, optionsText: 'Name', value: $data.AuthorId"></select>
    </div>
  </div>
        <div>
            <div class="item">Genre</div> 
            <input type="text" data-bind="value: $data.Genre"/>


        </div> 
 <div>
            <div class="item">Price</div> 
            <input type="text" data-bind="value: $data.Price"/>


        </div> 
 <div>
            <div class="item">Title</div> 
            <input type="text" data-bind="value: $data.Title"/>


        </div> 
<div>
            <div class="item">Year</div> 
            <input type="text" data-bind="value: $data.Year"/>


        </div> 
<div>
            <input type="button" value="Update" data-bind="click: $root.update"/>
            <input type="button" value="Delete Item" data-bind="click: $root.remove"/>
        </div>
    </li>
</ul>
</div>
```

but I have javascript error authors undefined because it is inside the foreach book and I am not sure when I used value: $data.AuthorId will give me the id or not

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can only guess your data structure, if the `author` object has a `Id`,

You should do

```
<select data-bind="options: $root.authors,
  optionsText: 'Name',
  optionsValue: 'Id',
  value: AuthorId"></select>
```

But there is another problem, if your `book.AuthorId` is not a `ko.observable` (this is my guess from your code), the above binding would not update the value of it when user selects different author.

Comment: The problem is I have javascript error authors undefined I think it might be because it is inside the foreach books. I am sure that the authors is defined as self.authors as in the tutorial?!

Comment: my bad, see updated answer, if your authors is in root level of your view model, refer it with $root.authors. And $data is not needed to refer AuthorId in current context.

Comment: Thank you, that was the problem $root.authors